# How to extract n chunks from a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, chunks

I have a dataset with 100,000 samples and 2 targets {Pass, Fail}
My main goal is to extract 5 chunks (groups) with 5 consecutive samples with the target "FAIL" randomly from the dataset.

My dataset:

```html
i           target             value
0            Fail               12
1            Fail               12
2            Fail               14
3            Fail               13
4            Fail               8 
5            Pass               40
6            Fail               12
7            Fail               7
8            Fail               9
9            Fail               11
10           Fail               19
11           Pass               44
12           Fail               16
13           Fail               4
.........................................
n
```

For the above dataset,

List1=[0,1,2,3,4]

List2=[6,7,8,9,10]

can be correct outcomes; however, the chunks should be picked randomly from the entire dataset.

P.S: the dataset is stored in an excel sheet and imported using pandas.

Comment: And what have *you* done to make that happen?

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I was able to extract one chunk from the dataset, but I amn't able to extract n chunks RANDOMLY

Comment: do you want `df[df.target.eq('Fail')].groupby('target').apply(lambda x: x.sample(5).index)` ?

Comment: @anky_91 my main issue is how to make the algorithm selects the chunks randomly from the dataset knowing that the order is important and I can't shuffle the dataset

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for your comment, Firstly the elements in the chunks should be consecutive (i.e. chunk_1 = [i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4] ) The chunks selection can be random as I can select a chunk from the beginning and maybe in the middle and from the end. I hope this is clear.  Maybe a good outcome would be: chunk_1;[122,123,124,125,126] , chunk_2: [1145,1146,1147,1148,1149], chunk_3: [33817,33818,33819,33820,33821].

Comment: Please write the question clearly. You say `5 consecutive samples with the target "FAIL` but your `List1` has 5 with target PAss

Comment: @mujjiga Thanks for your comment, it is an error. I will edit the question

Comment: @AlexDavies how about this `m=df[df.target.eq('Fail')].reset_index(drop=True)` and `np.random.choice([g.i.tolist() for _,g in m.groupby(m.index//5)],1)` ..? , you can pass the size parameter as per your requirement

Comment: @AlexDavies Did you have a look at [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard library?

Comment: Can the chunks overlap?

Comment: What do you want to do if you have a chunk of 6 consecutive Fail target values: reject it, or accept any of the 2 sub-chunks of 5 values?

Answer (score 1):

I would first identify all chunks of acceptable size, and then choose randomly among that list. The following code assumes a simple numerical index in the form of a RangeIndex (numbered from 0 to len-1). If the index is different, use `reset_index` to have a clean RangeIndex.

```
s = pd.Series(np.where(df2.target=='Fail', 1, np.nan), index=df2.index)
ends = np.random.choice(s[s.rolling(5).count()==5].index.values, 5)
```

`ends` contains the terminating index of 5 random sequences of 5 consecutive `Fail` rows in `df`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that randomly selects n chunks of 5 consecutive numbers in a numpy array, if there is any.

```
def get_chunks(x, n):
    chunks = np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x) != 1)[0]+1)  # split consecutives
    chunks = [c for c in chunks if len(c) >=5]  # get only chuncks with more than 5 elements
    if len(chunks) >= n:
        n_chunks = [chunks[i] for i in np.random.choice(range(len(chunks)), n, replace=False)]  # choose n chunks
        rs = [np.random.choice(np.arange(0, len(chunk) -4)) for chunk in chunks]  # get 5 elements from each chunk
        return [n_chunks[i][rs[i]: rs[i]+5] for i in range(len(n_chunks))]
    else:
        return None
```

And then apply it to the indices of your dataframe. With your example, we would get the following:

```
In [1]: indices = df.reset_index().groupby('target')['index'].apply(np.array)['Fail']
        get_chunk(indices, 2)        
Out[1]: [array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
```